# GWT client side unchecked exceptions

Tags: java, gwt, exception, smartgwt

I've been working on a project which uses GWT (and SmartGWT), which is (are) new to me.

Whenever runtime exceptions are thrown in the client (no RPCs involved) nothing happens. By that I mean the method does not continue executing, there are no alerts, there is nothing in the Javascript error console or the SmartGWT error console.

I'm assuming this isn't normal practice in GWT applications. Where are these errors (e.g. null pointers) normally logged/handled?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do catch them in the next way

```
GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  @Override 
  public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
    GWT.log(e.getMessage(), e); 
  }
});
```

You can replace the GWT.log by any other logging method.

Comment: That looks superb, just the sort of thing I expected. I can't believe this project's gone without it for 18 months, many thanks!